# Installing OpenCV with Conda

Tags: python, c++, opencv, conda

Installing packages to start running some code is perhaps the hardest part of my job.

Anways, I tried installing opencv for use in anaconda python 3.6 environment. And I get the error:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py36:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    libwebp-0.5.2              |           vc14_7         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    opencv-3.2.0               |    np112py36_204        92.0 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        93.1 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    libwebp: 0.5.2-vc14_7        conda-forge [vc14]
    opencv:  3.2.0-np112py36_204 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
libwebp-0.5.2- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:05 213.41 kB/s
opencv-3.2.0-n 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:48   1.97 MB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
PaddingError: Placeholder of length '34' too short in package conda-forge::opencv-3.2.0-np112py36_204.
The package must be rebuilt with conda-build > 2.0.
```

I am on a Windows System. I do not understand the error and searching isn't helping.

Any comments or suggestions to resolve the error are welcome.

Comment: That's probably not helping, but I can confirm that OpenCV works with Python 3.6. For what it's worth, I installed it with `pip` on my Windows.

Comment: @Rightleg thx, did you do just pip install openCV?

Comment: `pip search opencv` yields (among other) `opencv-python`, I guess that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the root conda environment.

And do `conda update conda`.

Then just `import cv2` and use it.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, OpenCV installs fine with `pip`.
Tested on Windows 10 with Miniconda and Python 3.6:

```
> pip search opencv
...
opencv-python
...

> pip install opencv-python
```

Tells me `Requirement already satisfied`.

To make sure it was correctly installed, run:

```
> python
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I am trying to make it work for a specific solution which says to install via conda only. Will there be any differences..I guess something else will break if I do otherwise..

Comment: @Rafael Yeah I understand. I hope someone knowing Conda better than I do will come by :)